What was the first game with a software mod?
Nowadays, any game that's even remotely popular has an abundance of mods. There are mods that make the game a bit nicer to look at, mods that add new content, mods that make life a living hell... etc.  Of course, mods didn't always exist.
What was the first game that someone made a mod for? What was the mod called, and what did it do?

For this question, a mod is defined as anything unofficial (i.e., community-made) that you can download, install, or insert into the hardware (such as a floppy disk) that modifies the game. Hardware modifications (such as snap-ons for arcade PCBs) don’t count.

To avoid confusion, I’m asking for the oldest mod, not the oldest game with a mod.

define "mod". Wolfenstein 3d had a level editor; it may have had more complex mods (I'm not certain; I only ever used the level editor), is that alone enough to count? NetHack is, in one sense, a mod of the original Hack. Is that a mod?

@qazmlpok See my revised question. Is that good?

Is downloading it from the internet a required step? I have no idea if that would disqualify NetHack, but I believe it would at least disqualify Spacewar!, which had people modifying it as part of the distribution.

@qazmlpok I mean, I don’t know how you would download/install something without internet.

@Daemons Floppy disks and snap-on modifications for arcade PCBs. I'm not immediately sure which of those would have come first.

@GGMG-he-him I don’t know if floppy disks count as downloading/installing something, but I’m fine with it being part of an answer. Not sure what you mean by snap-on modifications though?

@Daemons You could convert and modify arcade cabinets by changing their physical hardware, rather than downloading software. For example, a lot of Galaga cabinets are configured to have faster shot speed, and on the original boards that was accomplished by literally replacing one of the chips: https://mikesarcade.com/cgi-bin/store.pl?sku=GALAGARF
Or you could take a game and convert it to another game, legally or no. Super Missile Attack was a famous bootleg conversion of Missile Command, and they got sued by Atari over it. https://www.arcade-museum.com/Videogame/super-missile-attack

...So first software-based game mod?

It's hard to see how any mod could have become widespread without the internet for distribution. Unless it was distributed with a gaming mag.

Anyone that ever used a tape unit on an old "personal computer" knows that the oldest mod is the "dust speck". Just a single one on your tape could magically mod any side-effect to your game, including glitched graphics, random crashes and so on. These first mods would then carry on to the gen #1 home consoles and be known as the "Nes Gremlins". Still up to today you can often see lonely old followers of said cults as they play they ancient carts as an ocarina, quietly blowing on the cart dusty pins to appraise their forgotten gods.

@Time4Tea, go to your local computer club meeting with a stack of floppies, and copy "trainers" for games you're interested in (and sometimes the games themselves) from someone who already has them.  It was a remarkably effective way of distributing software.

Does Game Genie count as a mod? Or do you call it a "hardware modification" because it's a physical attachment, and disqualify it? Technically, it doesn't permanently modify the hardware though - more like augment and extend the capabilities.

@Mentalist I wouldn’t count that as software, no.

@Mentalist I had already written a troll answer since devices like the Game Genie do fit  each requisite in the post, but sadly even the Comodore 64 Multiface (1986) does not predate Castle Smurfenstein

If hardware wasn't excluded, changing resistors in PONG with a soldering iron would totally count.   But PONG didn't even have software, it was a completely hardware game.

@Time4Tea BBSes and networks such as the UK's "JANET" (Joint Academic NETwork) enabled file sharing around 10-15 years before the internet made this mainstream.

According to Wikipedia, the first game that was to anticipate and accommodate the creation of mods was Lode Runner, which came with its own level editor "which allowed users to make and save levels to share with other players on the same computer".
Lode Runner was released on June 23rd 1983.
But the Castle Wolfenstein mod Castle Smurfenstein, which replaced nazis with smurfs, dates from 1983 as well. I can't find an exact date, however.
Nevertheless, it is considered "the first non-commercial mod of a proprietary closed-source game done in violation of copyright", as someone here clarifies, to differentiate it from earlier game modifications that were anticipated by the developers - like in the case of Lode Runner, I imagine.
Castle Smurfenstein's developers, Dead Smurf Software (Andrew Johnson and Preston Nevins), released another modification earlier in the same year, another Smurfs parody, this time for the video game Dino Eggs, called Dino Smurfs. How this one differs from the aforementioned, and isn't considered the first mod while predating the other, I can't figure out.
Nevertheless, here's more information on these mods.

SpaceWar! was modded in 1961
In the early days of computing, it was extremely common to share and develop code written by others, and almost everyone who was using computers was a programmer. It is not surprising therefore that modding actually predates the first commercially sold games. The earliest documented example I can find is SpaceWar! which was originally developed by Steve Russell in 1961 but had major gameplay features added by Dan Edwards and Martin Graetz later that same year; and this modded game was distributed to others.
Perhaps there needs to be money involved, but in fact one of the first ever coin-operated video games, the 1971 Galaxy Game was a mod of SpaceWar! based on Russell's original code. The first ever commercial computer game, Computer Space was also based on SpaceWar! although it's not clear whether they derived any code from the original game so I'm not sure it counts as a mod.

I wonder to what degree what you refer to as "modding" isn't actually "developing": the game was created and developed by people who knew each other, and, as they explored the game and encountered weaknesses, asked for each other's help making it ("a cloud of hackers, tolerant when not actively implicated employers"). There was no pre-existing dev team, but that doesn't make it a mod. Can you elucidate this in your answer?

@Joachim: I don't think there is any such clear blue line between modders and developers. It's certainly not rare for modders to know developers, or even for developers to create mods for games that they worked on. I think it is better to leave such interpretation to the voter - those that favour a generous approach can upvote this answer; those that believe it should be a stricter rule can downvote it :)

But I do feel there is a clear line between a game and what constitutes a mod - the most important, in this context at least, because it is explicated in the question, is that a mod is considered something unofficial, and there doesn't seem to be anything unofficial about the development of Spacewars!, for one because all 'developers' communicated with each other during development.

@Joachim: some of them were, but Galaxy Game, for example, was independently developed. Also: plenty of mods get official recognition - Downfall for Slay The Spire being a notable example I played recently.

In the early days the source code was typically available for modification by others, which I would classify as a fork or remake rather than a "mod" in the modern sense.

@Miral I've heard mysterious that it wasn't so uncommon to trade games as source code printed on paper as that was cheaper than actually distributing storage media. Of course that's limited to rather rudimentary games. But distribution by source code rather than one compiled executable might have actually been a thing (likely for storage reasons or to invite contribution) in which case the line between fork and mod is blurry.

@JackAidley Sure, but your answer claims that Spacewar! is a mod, and you link to an article, suggesting that it backs up that claim, but, AFAICT, nothing in the article points to it actually being a mod. As requested earlier, can you address this in your answer, preferably by quoting from the article? | I'm also not saying mods have to be unofficial, but - again - that it is a limitation the OP has set. Galaxy Game (a reprogrammed version of Spacewar! intended for coin machines) also does not meet that requirement.

Joachim's answer covers well-documented mods, but I expect the first software game mods were trainers (cheat modifications such as infinite ammunition or invincibility) that were distributed with pirated software.  Since these were usually associated with software piracy, tracking their history is difficult; I expect they started to appear in the late 1970s with the rise of floppy-based home computers.

Can you list some examples of or references to this? I can easily imagine there being earlier occurrences, but haven't been able to find specific titles.

Mods themselves were often published in magazines as lists of memory locations to modify in order to increase the number of lives, gold, etc.

Trainers are mods made easy. Before trainers, there were people straight up memory hacking their games the hard way.
